# DotNetNuke SSL Fatal Error 552

Tags: dotnetnuke, ssl-certificate, dotnetnuke-5

We've just installed a SSL certificate in IIS and enabled SSL in DotNetNuke. We only secured one page, but now when we try to view the page it hangs. Most browsers aren't giving any valid reason and neither the windows event log nor the DNN log is showing any errors that would help.

Firebug shows that the initial request for the page is being made which has a 302 Found result, immediately followed by another request for the HTTPS resource. It waits a while then reports the request as aborted.

Opera reports the problem as: Secure connection: fatal error (552)

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured out that it was our ISP who was blocking port 443 so SSL requests were being blocked. Simple answer again.